# Example PHP code to read IDOC xml file from SAP outbound

Tags: php, saprfc

I'm trying to read SAP iDoc xml file using SAPRFC Lib. The iDoc file is created on application server & its available in specific path.

I have outbound Structure Name / Segment name for this iDOc.

I dont know how can i read iDoc xml file? .

Is there any PHP function / example code available to read it?

Notes : I have used netstat & tcpdump comment to see the IP, Port & its data. Transfer is happening between two server.